# How to repeat a question to a user until while loop condition is false?

Tags: java, do-while

I'm bulding a console application where I am trying to force a user to enter an `int` as a possible answer to a question otherwise the same question is repeated to the user.Thus, the user cannot move on without entering the proper data type.

below is my sample code.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int userInput = 0;
do {
       AskQuestion();
       if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
          userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) ;
```

While I know this can be done in C#, I'm not exactly sure how to do it in java without getting stuck in an infinite loop. How do I get my code to do what I want to do? Please help!

Comment: Don't ask the scanner if there are more ints in your `while`: if you want to ask a question until the user enters the correct int, check _the value they typed_. You capture that value already, so what should your `while` conditional look like instead?

Comment: do you also want to enforce a range to possible int that can be entered

Comment: was my answer any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int userInput;
while(true) {
    AskQuestion();
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    }
    scanner.next(); // consume non-int token
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this. It'a a pretty simple flag combined with the use of the Scanner class.

```
    boolean flag = false;
    int val = 0;
    while(!flag){
        System.out.println("Something");
        if(sc.hasNext()){
            if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                val = sc.nextInt();
                flag = true;
            }
            else{
                sc.next();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative which utilizes the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method along with the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method and a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) to ensure that the supplied string does indeed contain all numerical digits:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";
int desiredINT = 0;  // Default value.
while (desiredINT == 0) {
    AskQuestion();
    userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    if (userInput.matches("\\d+")) {
        desiredINT = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        if (desiredINT < 1 || desiredINT > 120) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input! The age supplied is not "
                             + "likely! Enter a valid Age!");
            desiredINT = 0;
        }
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input! You must supply an Integer "
                         + "value! Try Again...");
    }
} 
System.out.println("Your age is: --> " + desiredINT);
```

And the **AskQuestion()** method:

```
private void AskQuestion() {
    System.out.println("How old are you?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is nice and short one**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do askQuestion();
while(!scanner.nextLine().trim().matches("[\\d]+"));
```

**Tell me if you like it**

**Note** it just tell you if number was an int , and keeps repeating if not, but doesn't give you that int back , tell me if you need that, i shall find a way

Answer (score 0):

My solution might be a bit bloated, but I hope it's nice and clear what's going on. Please do let me know how it can be simplified!

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class

class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    String unit;

    // unit selector
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Did you measure ion feet or meters? Type 'meters' or 'feet': ");
        String isUnit = myObj.nextLine();
        if (isUnit.equals("feet") || (isUnit.equals("meters"))) {
            unit = isUnit;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter either 'meters' or 'feet'.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Use selected " + unit);

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nice to see new contributions coming in but this has an issue where the program will print these strings `Did you measure ion feet or meters? Type 'meters' or 'feet':` and `"Please enter either 'meters' or 'feet'."` in a `infinite` loop until your `break` condition is met.